# Open native sms inbox in SonyEricsson using android app

Tags: android

I am doing an app where a button click navigates to device's native sms inbox.

```
         Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.mms");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context , 0,intent,0)  ;         
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(viewId, pendingIntent );
```

Its working for Samsung devices. But not responding for the Motorola and SonyEricsson devices. can anyone suggest any other method to do the same activity common for all devices??

Thanks in advance